# Plotting SD at each point

Tags: plotting, graphics, error-tracking

I have a question to plot out the standard deviation for my graphs:
How can I plot out the SD values in each point such that the max and min will start from 0 and not an offset standard deviation (SD) values indicated on the graph [image]

I think that my first plot (first graph) is wrong as the raw signal that I have it does not have a huge variation at the beginning of the experiment (see second graph).   [image]

```
Percentgaittime={0.591716, 1.18343, 1.77515, 2.36686, 2.95858, 3.5503, 4.14201, 4.73373, 5.32544, 5.91716, 6.50888, 7.10059, 7.69231, 8.28402, 8.87574, 9.46746, 10.0592, 10.6509, 11.2426, 11.8343, 12.426, 13.0178, 13.6095, 14.2012, 14.7929, 15.3846, 15.9763, 16.568, 17.1598, 17.7515, 18.3432, 18.9349, 19.5266, 20.1183, 20.7101, 21.3018, 21.8935, 22.4852, 23.0769, 23.6686, 24.2604, 24.8521, 25.4438, 26.0355, 26.6272, 27.2189, 27.8107, 28.4024, 28.9941, 29.5858, 30.1775, 30.7692, 31.3609, 31.9527, 32.5444, 33.1361,33.7278, 34.3195, 34.9112, 35.503, 36.0947, 36.6864, 37.2781, 37.8698, 38.4615, 39.0533, 39.645, 40.2367, 40.8284, 41.4201,42.0118, 42.6036, 43.1953, 43.787, 44.3787, 44.9704, 45.5621, 46.1538, 46.7456, 47.3373, 47.929, 48.5207, 49.1124, 49.7041, 
50.2959, 50.8876, 51.4793, 52.071, 52.6627, 53.2544, 53.8462, 
54.4379, 55.0296, 55.6213, 56.213, 56.8047, 57.3964, 57.9882, 
58.5799, 59.1716, 59.7633, 60.355, 60.9467, 61.5385, 62.1302, 
62.7219, 63.3136, 63.9053, 64.497, 65.0888, 65.6805, 66.2722, 
66.8639, 67.4556, 68.0473, 68.6391, 69.2308, 69.8225, 70.4142, 
71.0059, 71.5976, 72.1893, 72.7811, 73.3728, 73.9645, 74.5562, 
75.1479, 75.7396, 76.3314, 76.9231, 77.5148, 78.1065, 78.6982, 
79.2899, 79.8817, 80.4734, 81.0651, 81.6568, 82.2485, 82.8402, 
83.432, 84.0237, 84.6154, 85.2071, 85.7988, 86.3905, 86.9822, 87.574, 
88.1657, 88.7574, 89.3491, 89.9408, 90.5325, 91.1243, 91.716, 
92.3077, 92.8994, 93.4911, 94.0828, 94.6746, 95.2663, 95.858, 
96.4497, 97.0414, 97.6331, 98.2249, 98.8166, 99.4083, 100.}
    
 
NormResC1Asc1 = {0., 0.000871409, -0.000740505, -0.00134163, -0.00125942, -0.00052254, 0.00112623, 0.000823583, 0.000802469, 0.00159639,0.00448126, 0.00411105, 0.00543972, 0.00489886, 0.00384889, 0.00542814, 0.00710673, 0.00598996, 0.00711033, 0.00883733, 0.00914232, 0.00852809, 0.0107261, 0.00855188, 0.00679089,0.00792223, 0.0086907, 0.00937034, 0.00964927, 0.0111331, 0.0140438,0.0199721, 0.0246155, 0.0332378, 0.051366, 0.0742839, 0.1064, 0.15128, 0.201599, 0.262696, 0.329243, 0.398985, 0.465571, 0.536221,0.609329, 0.685823, 0.761802, 0.8414, 0.911659, 0.977647, 1.04094, 1.09193, 1.13431, 1.18174, 1.2516, 1.32134, 1.39694, 1.46957, 1.53577, 1.60624, 1.66916, 1.70144, 1.72273, 1.74696, 1.77908, 1.814, 1.85053, 1.87412, 1.90048, 1.92134, 1.93887, 1.95001, 1.96512, 1.96056, 1.96346, 1.96428, 1.95449, 1.93845, 1.9243, 1.89434, 1.87925, 1.87431, 1.86644, 1.86, 1.84797, 1.82349, 1.80828, 1.79432, 1.77043, 1.72446, 1.68728, 1.64169, 1.59797, 1.5465, 1.49774, 1.45594, 1.4255, 1.39835, 1.37312, 1.36832, 1.36181, 1.36442, 1.35927, 1.33873, 1.31037, 1.29284, 1.26308, 1.24343, 1.21745, 1.17917, 1.14398, 1.11738, 1.09264, 1.06801, 1.04273, 1.01814, 0.991142, 0.970073, 0.951085, 0.931859, 0.912559, 0.890691, 0.868159, 0.85702, 0.847986, 0.843135, 0.838643, 0.832466, 0.830572, 0.826032, 0.814687, 0.808274, 0.800308, 0.790738, 0.782522, 0.769899, 0.757053, 0.743036, 0.726614, 0.709825, 0.690833, 0.672784, 0.654336, 0.636639, 0.625245, 0.616709, 0.607173, 0.601512, 0.596416, 0.586862, 0.576896, 0.568696, 0.557097, 0.550053, 0.53843, 0.525168, 0.511005, 0.497228, 0.480725, 0.466692, 0.446603, 0.426976, 0.407396, 0.389219, 0.371394, 0.353962, 0.337503, 0.321913, 0.309144}
    
     
NormResC1Asc2= {0., -0.00463601, -0.00683428, -0.00390607, 0.000367441,0.00320625, 0.0089447, 0.0143239, 0.0218172, 0.0260871, 0.026873, 0.0269342, 0.0265424, 0.0284897, 0.0282533, 0.0295213, 0.0320477, 0.0345993, 0.0422748, 0.0513945, 0.0606219, 0.070095, 0.0844906, 0.10046, 0.118654, 0.139828, 0.157375, 0.176484, 0.199233, 0.224248, 0.25413, 0.28797, 0.325762, 0.365045, 0.408375, 0.452922, 0.496558, 0.542801, 0.584341, 0.620449, 0.652293, 0.682289, 0.713376, 0.741512, 0.76776, 0.797997, 0.830404, 0.85925, 0.888021, 0.918696, 0.945173, 0.968696, 0.992999, 1.0116, 1.02261, 1.03377, 1.05325, 1.06956, 1.08246, 1.10057, 1.1215, 1.14386, 1.16751, 1.2005, 1.22458, 1.25248, 1.27889, 1.29383, 1.30232, 1.30679, 1.30262, 1.29932, 1.29325, 1.28014, 1.25872, 1.24713, 1.23259, 1.22369, 1.2135, 1.1936, 1.1759, 1.15637, 1.14176, 1.11292, 1.08733, 1.05505, 1.02753, 1.00353, 0.966075, 0.933721, 0.907243, 0.884606, 0.862536, 0.833083, 0.805812, 0.777462, 0.756732, 0.738711, 0.71982, 0.698264, 0.674954, 0.65101, 0.626243, 0.600121, 0.576264, 0.55032, 0.524915, 0.500051, 0.479191, 0.463178, 0.450019, 0.440994, 0.431436, 0.424989, 0.420254, 0.415529, 0.410082, 0.40431, 0.400778, 0.398645, 0.394126, 0.38353, 0.371454, 0.358892, 0.347324, 0.336793, 0.324772, 0.312889, 0.300652, 0.289391, 0.280647, 0.272934, 0.263288, 0.251555, 0.239668, 0.225725, 0.214904, 0.206203, 0.194028, 0.17972, 0.165406, 0.153531, 0.139882, 0.128162, 0.120311, 0.110714, 0.101462, 0.0909281, 0.0847471, 0.0795208, 0.0734919, 0.067886, 0.0597215, 0.0512292, 0.0392019, 0.0308578, 0.025025, 0.0175671, 0.0112968, 0.00525914, -0.00129158, -0.00639391, -0.00860829, -0.0091759, -0.0108808, -0.0113758, -0.0133053, -0.01256, -0.00781968}
    

NormResC2Asc1= {0., -0.000413181, 0.00220723, 0.00426789, 0.00602494, 
0.00677223, 0.00756772, 0.0074908, 0.009106, 0.00788936, 0.00682902, 
0.00611131, 0.00720546, 0.0105889, 0.0141865, 0.0172424, 0.0200145, 
0.0241169, 0.0288378, 0.0298885, 0.032149, 0.0340458, 0.036915,
0.0423055, 0.0495934, 0.0556933, 0.0630704, 0.0764393, 0.0883792,
0.104457, 0.121796, 0.139617, 0.153674, 0.172188, 0.189452, 0.207804, 
0.227732, 0.24717, 0.268627, 0.300658, 0.334622, 0.37111, 0.414429, 
0.468335, 0.525668, 0.590787, 0.656239, 0.716262, 0.782697, 0.847396, 0.901097, 0.947387, 0.984359, 1.01899, 1.05981, 1.10881, 1.15076, 
1.19628, 1.25961, 1.32766, 1.39752, 1.46449, 1.51884, 1.56601, 
1.60769, 1.64225, 1.65851, 1.67623, 1.70822, 1.74614, 1.77228,
1.80287, 1.83836, 1.86757, 1.9014, 1.92114, 1.90583, 1.89246, 1.87984, 1.86693, 1.85152, 1.82916, 1.80917, 1.79047, 1.77034, 
1.74984, 1.7306, 1.70442, 1.68531, 1.66426, 1.6246, 1.58603, 1.55539,
1.53111, 1.49312, 1.45477, 1.4083, 1.36957, 1.33886, 1.30745,
1.27649, 1.2565, 1.23757, 1.22113, 1.19621, 1.16869, 1.14693,
1.11991, 1.08172, 1.04074, 1.00755, 0.983868, 0.962412, 0.929364,
0.899639, 0.878907, 0.859796, 0.844274, 0.824928, 0.811923, 0.808778, 
0.810118, 0.808959, 0.803905, 0.801119, 0.794846, 0.789068, 0.779784, 
0.770125, 0.759239, 0.754489, 0.749345, 0.7444, 0.74036, 0.732717,
0.725308, 0.716205, 0.704226, 0.692984, 0.686264, 0.677772, 0.668642, 
0.661061, 0.652723, 0.644112, 0.636243, 0.618104, 0.596395, 0.575555, 
0.556985, 0.538922, 0.518694, 0.497542, 0.476761, 0.457425, 0.43507, 
0.404895, 0.372304, 0.340365, 0.308531, 0.283121, 0.259736, 0.23839, 
0.220333, 0.20847, 0.198072, 0.188096, 0.181486, 0.173802}
```

Comment: Basically I was trying to plot the upper and lower bound together with the mean graph. Thank you

Comment: Please load the (timeseries?) data from which you have calculated the mean and perhaps these other lists. Also explain what these data lists represent.  Are you calculating the element-by-element mean of the three lists and would you like to calculate SD for them as well? Thanks.

Comment: Yup I wanted to calculate the element by element, and the timeseries is added

Answer (score 2):

Let's start out by grouping the data by moment in time.

```
NormRes = Transpose[{NormResC1Asc1, NormResC1Asc2, NormResC2Asc1}];
```

We can then calculate the mean and standard deviation of the data at each moment in time using `Map[]`

```
NormResMean = Map[Mean, NormRes];
NormRezStDev = Map[StandardDeviation, NormRes];
```

Then plot using `Percentgaittime` as the time coordinate.

```
ListLinePlot[
 {Transpose[{Percentgaittime, NormResMean}],
  Transpose[{Percentgaittime, NormResMean + NormRezStDev}],
  Transpose[{Percentgaittime, NormResMean - NormRezStDev}]},
 PlotLegends -> {"Mean", "Mean+StDev", "Mean-StDev"}]
```

[image]